# <hr> cannot appear as a child of <select> (But it's clearly working)

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have a select for a country in an address. For the sake of convenience for the primary demographic of users, I created a duplicate 'United States' `<option>` at the top of the options list which I separated with a `<hr/>` to keep it visually separated from the otherwise alphabetized list.

Looks like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <hr/>
    <option ...
<select/>
```

React is giving me a warning in the console: `<hr> cannot appear as a child of <select>`. I've gotten this type of warning before when I put other things inside of selects expect those actually didn't work. The thing is that the line is rendering exactly as I intended and expected.

Should I be paying any attention to this warning? Usually I like to actually solve issues causing warnings but this seems like it's warning me against something that is actually supposed to work and is working as such.

Comment: In which browser is it working? For me - on Ubuntu 20.04 Edge 90, Chrome 89 and Firefox 86 - there is no line shown in the `<select>` element: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a73r0tce/). Nor should there be, since it is invalid HTML. You could - if you wish - wrap the duplicated 'more popular' areas in an `<optgroup>` element which would give some visual separation, but that's as much as the native `<select>` element can offer, unfortunately.

Comment: Chrome. I suspect it's more likely something to do with the bootstrap css in the page. optgroup sounds much more like the correct thing for the situation though.

Comment: Actually, upon experimentation I found the nicest looking and feeling solution to not use optgroups and instead just put an empty `<option disabled/>` in place of the `<hr>` I used